# Logic: How to move instruments in MIDI environment?

Tags: logic-pro

Is there a way to move around MIDI instruments in the MIDI environment view?
As visible in the screenshot, Inst 1 and 2 are overlapping. It seems this should be a simple matter of drag and drop, but I can't figure out where to drag.

[image: MIDI environment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move objects in the MIDI environment in Logic by click-hold-dragging the object name. Anywhere else on the object or the channel strip won’t work.

Comment: By object names you mean the labels underneath the elements ("Inst 1", "Inst 2"...)? This doesn't seem to work in my case. Clicking on these labels selects the corresponding element (changing color to bright grey), similar to right clicking.

Comment: I click-hold and drag and they seem to move just fine...I should have specified hold, I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: I just tried another project and they are moveable like you described. Unless there is some hidden option to lock these elements, it seems like the project I was working on became buggy. Annoying but not much of a loss. I will accept your answer anyway since it is obviously correct under normal circumstances and might help anyone else who comes across this question.

Comment: Logic? Buggy? Nah! Seriously though, you might be right about the lock, maybe look for a tiny lock icon in the environment somewhere. This program is fantastic but it does have me scratching my head sometimes too.

Comment: Actually it worked fine again after I restarted Logic, so I guess it wasn't a locking option. If I would have assumed a program error, I would have tried restarting earlier.